# 2-transitively, formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $X$ with $|X| \ge 2$ be a set on which $G$ acts. Then $G$ acts on $X \times X$ via $g \cdot (x, y) = (g \cdot x, g \cdot y)$. The action of $G$ on $X$ is called $2$-transitive if the $G$ action on $X \times X$ is transitive on the set of pairs of distinct elements of $X$.

For each $g \in G$ let $r_g$ be the number of fixed points of $g$ acting on $X$. Prove that if $G$ acts $2$-transitively on $X$ then $${1\over{|G|}}\sum_{g \in G} r_g^2 = 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ acts $2$-transitively, for any pair $(x, y) \in X \times X$ with $x \neq y$, it can be sent to any other pair $(z, w)$ with $z \neq w$. So all these pairs form an orbit of $X \times X$. The remaining elements of the set $X \times X$ are the diagonal $\Delta = \{(x, x) \in X \times X\}$. These form an orbit also since for any $x, y \in X$, there must be $g \in G$ with $g \cdot x = y$ $($there exists $g$ such that $g \cdot (x, y) = (y, x)$, so $g \cdot x = y)$. Thus $g \cdot (x, x) = (y, y)$, so $X \times X$ has exactly $2$ orbits. By Burnside's lemma, we have$${1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} r_g^2 = 2,$$since $r_g^2 =\,$# of fixed points of $g$ acting on $X \times X$.